Kotlin 2.0 Unable to read Kotlin metadata due to unsupported metadata kind: null
I'm moving to kotlin 2.0 and since migrating I'm getting the following error when trying to run my app.
Unable to read Kotlin metadata due to unsupported metadata kind: null.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction


My updated toml
[versions]
kotlin = "2.1.0"

[plugins]
jetbrainsCompose = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }
jetbrainsSerialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }
daggerHilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hiltAndroidCompiler" }

Update: seems to be related to version kotlin = "2.1.0" as downgrading to kotlin = "2.0.20" got me working.

Possibly related to https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3884. If applicable updating the Hilt version hiltAndroidCompiler should solve the issue.
